# Display none not working for angular navbar (but works for other components)

Tags: html, css, angular, internationalization

display none not working for angular navbar

I have a css style (display: none) that I use on many of my pages/components. It works well everywhere except the navbar
(Note: for anyone wondering why I'm using display: none, I am using this for translating interpolated items in i18n
Due to this note, also keep in mind that I want to hide but keep it in dom to retain  value.

Could someone help me understand why it doesn't work in this one place?

CSS:

```
.column-left {
  padding: 2rem;
  background-color: #3d8fcd;
  box-shadow: 3px 3px 10px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2); }

.column-right {
  background-color: #fff; }

@media screen and (min-width: 960px) {
  .main-content-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row nowrap;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: stretch;
    min-height: 100%; }
    .main-content-container .column-left {
      width: 30%;
      max-width: 30rem;
      flex-shrink: 0;
      z-index: 1; }
    .main-content-container .column-right {
      flex: 1 1;
      background-color: #fff; } }

.hide-element {
    display: none;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="main-content-container">

    <div class="column-left">
        <input placeholder="Nav" id="hinh" i18n-value="@@SoMeThIn_A1_1" value="Home" [class.hide-element]="true">
        <input placeholder="Nav" id="hinma" i18n-value="@@SoMeThIn_A1_2" value="My Account" [class.hide-element]="true">

        <app-navigation-column [nav-buttons]="navButtons" (clicked)="navigationColumn_click($event)" class="patient-nav">
        </app-navigation-column>

    </div>

    <div class="column-right" [@routerTransition]="getState(ot)">
        <router-outlet #ot="outlet"></router-outlet>
    </div>

</div>
```

I have tried:

```
display: none !important;
[style.display]="'none'"  
[style.visibility]="'hidden'"
[hidden]="hideElement"
[style.display]="hideElement?'none':'inherit'">
```

Comment: What are you trying to hide, `<input>` elements?

Comment: If you inspect the dom, do the inputs actually have your class? I might try something like this: [ngClass]="{ 'hide-element' : true }"

Comment: [hidden]="true" ?

Comment: @AmirArbabian I am using hidden elements because Angular does not support internationalization of interpolated items, this is a workaround.

Comment: @Cyril that worked ! If you want to make it an Answer I can mark it as the Answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this on your comp :

```
[hidden]="true"
```